# Rails Categories - checking if a user category intersects category array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm having some trouble understanding the correct way to go about this.

- a user can subscribe to categories (8 total)
- properties belong to categories
- tickets can be created. Tickets can have either one or multiple properties.
- if a ticket is created, and a user is subscribed to a category AND the created ticket includes that property, the user will receive an email notification.

This is what I had initially. I thought it was working decently, but the issue is:

if a ticket is created with multiple properties that span across different categories, and a user is only subscribed to one of those categories, **they will not get the email.** They should get an email.

example:

- User A is only subscribed to one category: category one.
- a ticket is created with 3 properties.
- property 1 comes from category 1, property 2 comes from category 2, property 3 comes from category 3.
- since User A is only subscribed to category one, they will not receive a ticket, **but they should**: hence an issue with my code.

I know the below is bad because that will only put the final property.category.name into `@ticket_category`

```
@ticket.properties.each do |property|
    @ticket_category = property.category.name
end


@people_for_email = @sub_emails.select {|user| user["categories"].include?(@ticket_category)}

@emails_for_email = @people_for_email.map {|emails| emails["name"]}
```

then we send the email

```
UserNotifier.ticket_created(@emails_for_email).deliver_now
```

I've tried setting `@ticket_category` to an array `[]` and using `<<` within the block. Using `.any?` seems like it would work well here, but I haven't had much luck setting it up without returning argument errors. Any idea the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&` to get the intersection of two arrays. Then `present?` will return `true` if there are *any* elements in the array. So something like:

```
@ticket_categories = []
@ticket.properties.each do |property|
    @ticket_categories << property.category.name
end


@people_for_email = @sub_emails.select do |user|
  intersection = user["categories"] & @ticket_categories
  intersection.present?
end

@emails_for_email = @people_for_email.map {|emails| emails["name"]}
```

(I didn't test this, so there might be typos)

Comment: Off topic for this question, but you can simplify the `@ticket.properties.each` loop by using `@ticket.properties.map`

Comment: Excellent, that worked like a charm. And updated that loop using .map. Cheers :)